# How to add a percent sign to my counting loader in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem adding the percent sign to my counter which is for a loader, I'm trying to add the percent sign next to the numbers and I can't figure out a way to do that, I tried using the +'%' code Javascript but it doesn't work...

Can anyone please help?

```js
$('.count').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 1500,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="count">100</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
$(this).text(Math.ceil(now) + "%");
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use a pseudo after in css

```css
p:after{
  content:"%"
}
```

```html
<p>100</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Zamboney!

Comment: You probably want to use `p.count:after { ... }` lest you apply that to every paragraph on the page...